# How to change Sitefinity responsive navigation widget text?

Tags: sitefinity

In a Sitefinity 10.2 Project I have two Navigation widgets. When applying rules for responsive design they reduce to 'Hamburger'- style menues, what is fine (see attached Image).
My  question is how to change the text displayed ('menu' in this case)?
I could not find anything about this in documentation or Forums.

Best regards
Udo
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWV0J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the widget template toggle menu you will see which label it is using. You will change the text through Labels and Messages.

**Access and Modify Label**

- Administration >> Labels and Messages
  [image: Access Labels and Messages]
- Search 'toggle'
  [image: Search toggle for correct label]
- Edit the *ToggleMenuLabel* [image: Edit the label]

**Access Widget Template**

- Design >> Widget Templates
- Search 'toggle' 
  [image: Search for toggle template]
- Open widget template
- View the text/label that is being used 
  [image: Label being used identified]

Comment: So, if I want to have different texts for different menues I need to create a new template for each of them?

Comment: I think that would be the simplest approach unless the text is language based then I would use translations and input the correct value for the correct translation in labels/messages.